# Do I need to replace 14-year water heater which looks new and functions well

Tags: water-heater

I have Googled extensively and people say a water heater (40 gallon tank, gas type) lasts 8 to 12 years. My water heater is 14 year old and functions well. It looks like brand new too.

For 14 years I did not do any maintenance work on it.

Do I need to replace it? Or should I wait until it breaks?

Comment: If you have no problem with the spill, wait till it breaks. Otherwise, replace it. It won't be long before you are forced to replace it anyway.

Comment: Usually with water heating tanks, it is the tank leaking all over the place that happens first, not the heater dying.

Comment: Funny everyone commenting about leaks, OP mentions nothing about leaks. No maintenance in 14 years is nice. The only thing to wonder is about sediment and condition of heating elements and the sacrificial anode?

Comment: My gas-fired water heater has sat undisturbed since I installed it 19 years ago and it works perfectly. I personally am not an advocate of back-flushing or any other maintenance other than ensuring that it is clean and the air ports are free of lint/debris. I have no intention of replacing it unless the steel tank itself rusts through. Other stuff (thermocouple, gas control, TP-valve) I will not touch until/unless I need to,

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- have you checked the anode on it? that's what governs a tank's life more than anything else, as that anode is one of the keys to keeping the tank from rusting thru...

Comment: To the OP: is pulling and checking the tank's anode an option?

Comment: I have two gas water heaters , I wait until there is a problem.  Replaced the first two at about 13 years; I saw one had a tiny leak into the safety pan so I checked the other and it was the same.  Then after 10 years something failed in the thermostat, replaced rather than repaired. Then at about 13 years a valve failed  and I decided to replace the water heater although it had no problem . However it is in the attic and for various reasons I was conservative and replaced it.

Comment: The anode rod is *one* of the corrosion prevention devices, but IMO not **the** most important. The most important is the internal glass-lining on the tank. I have never checked the anode on my 19yo heater and I don't intend to (I am certain it is long gone). The longevity I have experienced is proof enough for me that the importance of the anode rod (at least under my use-conditions: hard water, heavy use household of 5) is over-stated. I am a firm believer of not disturbing the tank in any way, unless necessary (and of "don't fix it if it ain't broke").

Comment: Decades ago the practice was to connect the WH with sweated solid copper. This completed the circuit of an electrochemical cell and thereby promoting corrosion of the tank. Modern practice is to use a flexible coupling with an insulating plastic seal in the end connected to the tank. This disconnects the steel tank from the pipes and could lead to a much longer service life for a tank WH.

Comment: I have a large rental property that has an 80 gallon HW that is probably 40 years old and working fine.   I don't know the maintenance history on it.  HWs don't generally catastrophically fail. They either spring a leak due to the tank rusting thru or one of the heating elements fail, assuming an electric WH (the elements are easily replaceable).  I think the best approach is to "run to failure", just like the power companies do (sarcasm intended).

Comment: When people say something lasts X to Y years that is usually an average.  40 to 60% will need replacing in that time frame.  Others will fail a lot sooner, and some will last longer.

Comment: Yes, check the anode.   I am not the biggest fan of "sample sizes of 1".

Answer (score 2):

Lots of comments but, if it is working don’t fix it!
I have found a houses with 15-20 year old water heaters.
I flushed it installed a new anode and it still worked at that point.
As long as it is doing it’s job why do anything other than basic maintenance like flushing and replacing the anode, if it fails a week after you replace the anode pull it and save it it may work in your new tank in a few years.

Comment: How much force is required to unscrew an anode rod which has been in place for 14 years? I once tried to unscrew an anode rod in a tank which was being replaced due to failure and could not break it loose.

Comment: @jim Stewart how much force was it put in with? Every one will be different including if anti seize was used.